# wget download aspx page

Tags: download, html, wget

I want to download the web page http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/ModelViewController.aspx using **wget**, so I simply used the really basic command:

`wget http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/ModelViewController.aspx`

What I received was a file with the `.aspx` extension, which could not be displayed correctly in a regular browser.

How can I download that web page?

Answer (score 4):

Courtesy of the [wget manual page](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#HTTP-Options) (first result of a web search on "wget options", btw):

```
wget -E http://whatever.url.example.com/x/y/z/foo.aspx
```

If you also wish to download all related media (CSS, images, etc.), use `-p`, possibly with `--convert-links` (rewrites the page for offline viewing):

```
wget -Ep --convert-links http://whatever.url.example.com/x/y/z/foo.aspx
```

Comment: i tried your answer,it seems that wget just downloads the page and appends the suffix in **html**,still could not display the downloaded "html" page correctly,although better than doing nothing,specifically,code highlighting and several pictures are lost.

Comment: @Tracy: You didn't mention that you also wanted to download the associated images and other data.

Answer (score 0):

The file will actually be displaying correctly, you can rename it to a .html file and you will be able to confirm this. The server-side technology used by the webserver doesn't effect wget

Edit: my comments below this were wrong, thanks for the commentor for pointing it out, have removed them for future readers

Comment: That is incorrect, `wget` can do that quite easily (`-p --convert-links`, this functionality has been there for years). Note also that wget can do the renaming for you (`-E`). See the manual: http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Advanced-Usage

Comment: @Haz, i did that renaming thing,but like i said in the comment on @Piskvor 's answer,code highlighting and several pictures are lost,and the terrible font.

Comment: @Piskvor，by using the option -p and --convert-links(equivalent to -k),all i get is a folder containing files related to the page downloaded,however,there is still an aspx extension file which has the same problem,i could not find an nice normal html page after digging down the folder.

Comment: @Tracy: Well, have you tried, y'know, *combining* the switches? `-E -p --convert-links` (and btw, there's more good stuff in that manual)

Comment: @Piskvor, seems i missed the -E option,sorry for that and i am really appreciate your help !

Answer (score 0):

```
$ wget \
     --recursive \
     --no-clobber \
     --page-requisites \
     --html-extension \
     --convert-links \
     --restrict-file-names=windows \
     --domains example.org \
     --no-parent \
         www.example.org/tutorials/html/
```

from this page : http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/downloading-entire-web-site-wget